# Why does the assignment of a short variable to an Integer reference produce a compile time error?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, boxing

I have the following code in Java :

```
class Boxing
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            short s = 10;
            Integer iRef = s;
        }
    }
```

Why does it produce an error in compilation? If I explicitly typecast the short to an integer in the expression, it compiles successfully. Since I'm using a short in an expression isn't the type of that supposed to be an integer by default without requiring the explicit case?

Comment: I would do `int iRef = s`.

Comment: That's not my question. My question is why does Integer iRef = s not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to have two things happening here: widening and auto-boxing.

Unfortunately, Java does only one of the two automatically. The reason for that is most likely that autoboxing was introduced fairly late (in  Java5), and they had to be careful to not break existing code.

You can do

```
int is = s;    // widening

Short sRef = s;   // autoboxing

Integer iRef = (int) s;  // explicit widening, then autoboxing
```

Comment: You actually probably want `int is = s & 0xffff;` for widening, since it's common to use shorts in Java as unsigned 16-bit integers (there is no unsigned short type in Java other than `char`).

Answer (score 2):

Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:

> From type boolean to type Boolean
>
> From type byte to type Byte
>
> From type short to type Short
>
> From type char to type Character
>
> From type int to type Integer
>
> From type long to type Long
>
> From type float to type Float
>
> From type double to type Double
>
> From the null type to the null type

Reference: [Conversions and Promotions Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here´s the documentation from [JLS 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> From type boolean to type Boolean
>
> From type byte to type Byte
>
> From type short to type Short
>
> From type char to type Character
>
> From type int to type Integer
>
> From type long to type Long
>
> From type float to type Float
>
> From type double to type Double
>
> From the null type to the null type

Basicly the direct conversion from `short` to `Integer` is not part of the autoboxing process of `Java`.

The autoboxing, as provided above, is only able to implicity cast the representing primitive type to it´s representing Wrapper class. Since this is not the case it will cause a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

In the code considered.

```
class Boxing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        short s = 10;
        Integer iRef = s;
    }
}
```

Integer extends java.lang.Number. And java.lang.Short also extends java.lang.Number. But Short and Integer are not directly related if you wanted you can run the following program.

```
class Boxing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        short s = 10;
        Number iRef = s;
    }
}
```

It will run without producing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Java attempts to perform auto-widening, then auto-boxing, then auto-upcasting, but will not perform two of these for the same assignment. This is explained and diagrammed [here](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/auto-widening-auto-boxing-auto-upcasting-java/), for the related case of method parameter assignment.